# How to fetch row of unknown ROWTYPE in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

I have table in oracle with definitions of lists. Each definition is sql string, that returns table with 'd' and 'r' columns. I want get some 'd' value by 'r' value. 
**Example:**
My query string is: `SELECT SOME_COLUMN d, SOME_COLUMN2 r from SOME_TABLE order by 1`
My PL/SQL code is:

```
DECLARE
        query_str VARCHAR2(2000) := 'SELECT SOME_COLUMN d, SOME_COLUMN2 r from SOME_TABLE order by 1';
        return_str VARCHAR2(2000);
        TYPE LovCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
        v_lov_cursor LovCurTyp;
    --And there is my problem:
        lov_record UNKNOWN_TYPE_OF_SOME_TABLE%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
        OPEN v_lov_cursor FOR query_str;
        LOOP
        FETCH v_lov_cursor INTO lov_record;
        EXIT WHEN v_lov_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        --Get return_str here
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE v_lov_cursor;

        return return_str;
END;
```

So my question is: **How to fetch row of unknown ROWTYPE or maybe there is another way to do something like I describe?**

Comment: Not clear with what you are asking. Can you explain in detail on what you really want to achieve?

Comment: This question comes up a LOT.  Does the query in `query_str` really need to be dynamic?  If so, you need to `DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER` to convert `v_lov_cursor` to `DBMS_SQL` so that you can describe the columns and fetch them without knowing their names or types ahead of time.